# How to use FireBase Authentication for SSO

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on

How can one use Firebase to SSO into some product?

Firebase is a *federated* IdP, meaning, they handle the auth flows for other IdPs, ie Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

So how can I set up a product with SSO that is expecting some kind of Auth flow, ie OIDC, SAML, when FireBase doesn't necessarily do that?  Note, I am comfortable building my own login pages and using the FireBase SDK, I'm just not sure where to start.

Let's take Google for example.  I can easily setup Google SSO for my product.  I just generate a client ID/Secret in the Google Dashboard, and then use Google's OAuth flow.

1. My product initiates the login and redirects to Google for logins
2. Google identifies my user and redirects to my product's callback URL
3. Done, user is logged in

How would I do the same thing in FireBase, which is a sort of middleman between my product and Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own user auth system, and you want to integrate that with Firebase Auth for the purpose of creating accounts that integrate with other Firebase products, you can write a [custom authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).  Your backend will take the user's credentials and [create a custom auth token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that the app can use to sign in the user.

Comment: I don't have my own auth system, I have my own product that I want to enable SSO with USING Firebase and all of the Firebase supported authentication.  not sure how to do that

Comment: Firebase Auth doesn't do that.  You either choose an auth provider, or implement your own.

Comment: If you upgrade to the new 'Google Cloud Identity Platform' (which is basically a newer version of Firebase Auth), then you can add custom SAML / OpenID Connect providers: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform You can read more about it + specific links out to related doc pages in this question I just answered recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078218/integrate-custom-oauth-provider-with-firebase-auth-signinwithredirect/67955260#67955260